# Symplectic form on $\Omega^0(X,End(E))$

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, sg.symplectic-geometry, vector-bundles

Let $E\rightarrow X$ be a holomorphic vector bundle over a Kahler manifold. Is there a natural symplectic form on the space $\Omega^0(X,End(E))$ ?

For example on $\Omega^1(X,End(E))$ we have the Atiyah-Bott form$$\Omega(a,b)=\int_Xtr(a\wedge b)\omega^{n-1}/(n-1)!.$$

Is there a natural extension to all the degrees? in particular degree 0.

Comment: No, in general not. Consider a holomorphic line bundle $E$, then $End(E)$ is the trivial holomorphic line bundle. There is no natural (complex) symplectic structure on the space of functions.

Comment: @Sebastian why isnt the following true: Put a Hermitian metric on $E$, it induces a Hermitian metric on $End(E)$. Using a volume form (for example $\omega^n$) we obtain by integration a Hermitian metric on the space of sections of $End(E)$. Take the imaginary part and you get a symplectic form